# Get angular controller injects list

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I write Unit tests for angular controllers with Karma. It looks like:

```
describe('TestController', function() {

    var $scope, $rootScope, service1, sevice2, service3, $controller;

    beforeEach(module('TestModule'));

    beforeEach(function() {  
        inject(function($injector) {
            service1= $injector.get('service1');
            service2= $injector.get('service2');
            service3= $injector.get('service3');
            $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();

            $controller = $injector.get('$controller')('TestController', {
                $scope: $scope
            });            
        });
    });

    /* it blocks */
});
```

As can You see all controllers injects i get from $injector by hands, step by step.

So  question is, can i simply get list of all TestController injects?

controller function sample for this test:

```
function($scope, $rootScope, service1, sevice2, service3)
```

i need get:

```
['$scope', '$rootScope', 'service1', 'sevice2', 'service3'] or similar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [annotate](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24injector#methods_annotate) method of the injector object will give you a list of dependencies.